# PIC Microcontroller And Dataman Connection Problem

Tags: pic, programmer, icsp

I'm working on my first project with PIC18F4620. I'm using Dataman 48pro2C programmer and it's software. I'm using 5 pin header to connect the microcontroller to the programmer. The pins are VPP, GND, VDD, PGD, PGC. I uploaded other code to the microcontroller before but I had to remove the header and reconnect it. (I connected the header directly to the microcontroller with jumper cables because I forgot to add the programming pins to the PCB) Now whenever I try to upload the code, I get this error:

[image]

I don't think I made a mistake when connecting the pins, I checked them many times. And I don't think the problem is bad device either. Because when I power up the circuit with the old code it works fine.

My questions are:

1- Should I try to upload the code while the circuit is powered up? (I just tried without voltage input)

2- VPP pin is connected directly to the header, without any resistor. It worked that way before but should I put a resistor in between microcontroller and the header?

3- Could there be any other reason why microcontroller can't connect?  Thanks

[image]

I color coded the jumper cable locations:
(Please ignore the 16F877 label)

[image]

Comment: where on your PCB is the 5-pin header for programming?

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios I  unfortunately forgot to include that part in the PCB. Instead I connected the header externally with jumper cables.

Comment: might be worth annotating where the jumper cables are connected on the PCB diagram? just a thought

Comment: @pm101 You're right. I edited the question. I would appreciate if you could check that out again.

Comment: Okay, you soldered the cables on the MCU's pins directly. There might be some residue of flux left behind and it "shorts" the pins with each other (with a resistance of possibly kOhms or Mohms but its enough to stop the programming action). Have you tried cleaning the PCB with Acetone? (not isopropanol, its not enough to clean between pins and cannot clean properly if you dont rub it). Acetone might clean between pins without rubbing it